# Hayes process macro (v4.3) - Multicategorical IV Mediation: omnibus and effect size questions?

Tags: regression, spss

I have two main questions - but I'll give a brief background first.

I've run a mediation logistic regression using Hayes Process macro (v4.3), model 4. It's a parallel mediation, with a categorical IV and 4 mediators.
My IV is family type (single parent, social care, multigenerational, etc.), with 'both biological parents' as the reference category. They're being regressed onto aggression scores.

My questions are:

1. I'm just writing out my results, and I appreciate that the output breaks it down into each category vs. the reference, but I also note that there is an 'omnibus test of direct effect of X on Y'. Would I be right in thinking that this is the overall effect of family type on aggression? So if this is significant, I could say family structure predicts aggression, and then break each categorical output down?
2. Is there a way to work out effect sizes for a categorical aggression? I note it isn't an option on v4 of Hayes Process, but was on v3. Can I do this another way?

Thank you so much in advance!